# Spring boot - Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm new to spring. I currently have this error when i try launching. I believe either missing some dependencies or my persistence declaration.

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at com.ridzuan.TcfbRosterApplication.main(TcfbRosterApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted

Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table leave (id integer not null auto_increment, end_date datetime, is_approved bit not null, remarks varchar(255), start_date datetime, staff_id varchar(255), primary key (id))]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
... 22 common frames omitted

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leave (id integer not null auto_increment, end_date datetime, is_approved bit no' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
... 32 common frames omitted
```

Here is my code structure

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.spf</groupId>
<artifactId>TCFBRoster</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>TCFBRoster</name>
<description>TCFBRoster</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Leave.java

```
    package com.ridzuan.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Leave {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private String remarks;
private boolean isApproved;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "staff_id")
private Staff staff;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public boolean isApproved() {
    return isApproved;
}

public void setApproved(boolean isApproved) {
    this.isApproved = isApproved;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Leave [id=" + id + ", startDate=" + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", remarks=" + remarks
            + ", isApproved=" + isApproved + "]";
}

}
```

Staff.java

```
package com.ridzuan.domain;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Staff {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "identification", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String identification;
private String name;
private int phone;
private String password;
private String team;
private boolean isActive;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "staff", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Leave> leaveList;

public String getIdentification() {
    return identification;
}

public void setIdentification(String identification) {
    this.identification = identification;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public void setTeam(String team) {
    this.team = team;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public List<Leave> getLeaveList() {
    return leaveList;
}

public void setLeaveList(List<Leave> leaveList) {
    this.leaveList = leaveList;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

Heres my application.properties

Been stuck for quite a while and dont understand where did i go wrong. Really hopeful for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringBoot JPA Hibernate: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530625/springboot-jpa-hibernate-error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate of that since all the user has to do is look at the CAUSE exception, and your linked post has a different reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL being invoked is

```
create table leave (id integer not null auto_increment, end_date datetime, 
    is_approved bit not null, remarks varchar(255), start_date datetime, 
    staff_id varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

Your message says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'leave (id integer not null auto_increment, end_date datetime, is_approved bit no' at line 1
```

The reason is that your table name `leave` is a reserved keyword. Sadly for you your JPA provider doesn't automatically quote keywords for you, so you have to specify a different table name, or put quote marks around the name in the `@Table` annotation. Either that or use a JPA provider that auto-quotes reserved keywords ...

Answer (score 0):

For your Staff Entity
you'll notice all of those generate id's of type long, short or int, not of type String.
If you want String id you can use UUID an as an id

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name ="uuid", strategy = "uuid2") 
@Column(name = "identification")
private String identification;
```